# Check if CSS display: contains the word "block" then hide element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see what is the best way for css display style contains the value block.  Because it can be block, flex-block, inline-block etc...

I want to use jQuery code like:

```
if ($.inArray("block", $("#myelement").css()) > 0)
{
  $("#myelement").css("display", "none");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($("#myelement").css("display").indexOf("block") != -1)
{
    $("#myelement").hide();
}
```